# DefaultMessageListenerContainer ignore if queue is missing

Tags: spring-jms

I have an app deployed in Tomcat. I have a activemq listener configured as a Spring bean. On starting Tomcat server, my app is able to connect to the broker, but for some reason the queue is missing. Due to this reason the Tomcat server doesn't start up. Is there a way to skip the listener-startup if the queue is missing?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working sample code describing your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Set `autoStartup` to false on the DMLC.

Then, in your application, try to `start()` the container yourself and catch any exceptions.